# Kubuntu: apt-get install of php5-dev: libtool version mismatch?

Tags: kubuntu, aptitude, packages

(Warning, clueless-newbism ahead.)

Background info: I'm actually trying to install/upgrade **xdebug**.

**`sudo pecl install xdebug`** yields:

```
downloading xdebug-2.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.0.5.tgz (289,234 bytes)
............................................................done: 289,234 bytes
67 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

A quick google tells me that `phpize` is a part of a package called `php5-dev`, so off I ran to install that.

My *problem* is that using **`sudo apt-get install php5-dev`** fails with this output:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-dev: Conflicts: libtool (>= 2.2) but 2.2.6a-4 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

`2.2.6a-4` is greater than `2.2`, so I'm not sure why it's hanging itself up at that point. I'm guessing the fact that it's not entirely numeric is throwing apt-get off?

I can probably install **xdebug** manually (though I've never done this before, so picture me with a <s>deer</s> clueless-newb in headlights look here, violently shaking my head and begging for a simpler solution) rather than via `pecl` / *`aptitude`*, but is there a way I can make *`aptitude`* install **php5-dev** despite the bogus 'broken package' claim? Is it even bogus, or am I misreading the error message?

Alternatively: Could I install **`phpize`** in some other way (e.g. via `pear` or `pecl`)?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Comment: I still get the same error, unfortunately. Though I've managed to find an alternate way of installing `xdebug` by now that doesn't require `phpize` (mind, this was about a month ago, I'm not sure I could reconstruct). Still, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try use:

```
aptitude install php5-dev
```

it will tell you that the solution to your problem is to downgrade libtool to version 1.5.26-4+lenny1 and if you accept the solution it will install the older libtool version and php5-dev installation will be successful after that without any conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtool/libtool_1.5.26-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get remove libtool
sudo dpkg -i libtool_1.5.26-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

If you're running 64-bit you have to change i386 to amd64.